# Python: How do I store a nonlocal variable's value in an inner function when it's created?

Tags: python, function, scope, runtime

If I have an outer function returning an inner function like so:

```
def outer():
    outer_var = 1

    def inner():
        return outer_var

    outer_var = 2
    return inner
```

Calling `outer()()` will return 2. However, I want the inner function to return the value outer_var had when the inner function was created, not when it was called.

The only solution I could come up with was:

```
def outer():
    outer_var = 1

    def inner(inner_var=outer_var):
        return inner_var

    outer_var = 2
    return inner
```

Calling `outer()()` will now return 1. Is there a better solution that doesn't need kwargs? I don't think it's necessary to mention that in my actual code outer_var will only be known at runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### I was going to suggest this:

```py
def outer():
    outer_var = 1

    temp_outer_var = outer_var
    def inner():
        return temp_outer_var

    outer_var = 2
    return inner
```

But your solution is more elegant!

#### No

I don't think there is a more elegant solution than these.

Comment: Well in my case I create callback functions inside a loop, so assigning to a different variable won't help as the variable will change in every iteration.